# Autocomplete Alembic Commands

Tags: bash, autocomplete, terminal, alembic

Is there any way to add alembic commands to the bash so that the alembic command autocomplete works like git?

For example, in [Quick Tip: Autocomplete Git Commands and Branch Names in Bash](http://code-worrier.com/blog/autocomplete-git/) the author shows how to add git commands to `.bash_profile` how can we achieve the same thing for alembic?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a bash autocompletion script for alembic:
https://gist.github.com/soyo42/65aa0b4d47c76bfb1e069d8989dd5ace

It is based on alembic-1.6.5.
The only advanced feature by now is fetching history to provide `--tag` values for upgrade/downgrade.

Feel free to use, comment or modify.
Good luck.